# Magento Dataflow Advance Profile To Export Customer in Google Contact Format

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, xml, export, dataflow

I have difficulty to find any guide relating to this subject.
Basically, I want to export all customer using **magento dataflow profile export** to csv, in a way so I can just import the csv to the google contact directly. Below are fields that needed by google contacts:

1. Given Name
2. Family Name
3. E-mail 1 - Type
4. E-mail 1 - Value
5. Phone 1 - Type
6. Phone 1 - Value

Number 1,2,4,6 is using data from field mapping.
The question is, how can I fill number 3 and 5

- Number 3 should filled by "* Work"
- Number 5 should filled by "Mobile"

Below is my Actions XML:

```
    <action type="customer/convert_adapter_customer" method="load">
        <var name="store"><![CDATA[2]]></var>
        <var name="filter/email"><![CDATA[fara]]></var>
        <var name="filter/group"><![CDATA[4]]></var>
        <var name="filter/adressType"><![CDATA[default_billing]]></var>
    </action>

    <action type="customer/convert_parser_customer" method="unparse">
        <var name="store"><![CDATA[2]]></var>
        <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    </action>

    <action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
        <var name="map">
            <map name="firstname"><![CDATA[Given Name]]></map>
            <map name="lastname"><![CDATA[Family Name]]></map>
            <map name="email"><![CDATA[E-mail 1 - Value]]></map>
            <map name="shipping_telephone"><![CDATA[Phone 1 - Value]]></map>
        </var>
        <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
    </action>

    <action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
        <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
        <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
        <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
    </action>

    <action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
        <var name="type">file</var>
        <var name="path">var/export</var>
        <var name="filename"><![CDATA[test.csv]]></var>
    </action>
```

This is the output:
[image]

However, below is the expected output
[image]

How can I achieve that?
Thank you

Comment: How can we add billing and shipping address ?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.integromat.com/en/integrations/google-sheets/magento

Read this .

https://docs.magento.com/m2/2.1/ce/user_guide/system/data-csv.html

Or

This official documentation .

Or you can buy module from magento marketplace.